# How to query up to nth level based on direction in Gremlin PipeLine

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I would like to know know to get child nodes up to the `n`th level based on direction in a Gremlin PipeLine. I want to write a generalized query that is used to query up to the `n`th level.

For example, suppose I have a vertex A. Its immediate children are [B,C,D] (level 1). The children at second level are [E,F,G].I want to write a query that give the children at any particular level(ie, at 1 or at 2)

Comment: Hi! This post came to me in a review queue for Help and Improvement and I've edited it a little. . There are some further things you could might consider to make the question more useful to other users that find it in the future. E.g. 1) can you post a minimal example input and desired output? 2) clarify are you referring to Gremlin pipeline the concept or the specific class? [`GremlinPipeline`](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/blob/master/gremlin-java/src/main).

Comment: edit to make question clearer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use loop: http://gremlindocs.com/#branch/loop. You can limit the number of times you loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Vertex> vertexList = new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("mgrNo", 312552919).out("manager of").loop(1, new PipeFunction<LoopBundle,Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean compute(LoopBundle bundle) {
            //System.out.println("in loop bundle");
            return  bundle.getLoops() < n;
        }

    }).toList();
```

where `n` is the level that you want to query upto.